# Does Bucket4j provide customization for applying different rate-limits to different APIs?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, rate-limiting

I am planning to use bucket4j in spring mvc web application for limiting the requests to multiple APIs. Does Bucket4j provide some flexibility with limiting for different endpoints / https methods (GET/POST/PUT) ?
Also, is there any third party library, that does so ?

Whatever I try to search I am getting Bucket4j as the answer. Also, I have started implementing own logic for rate-limiting, but would take up most of my time